# Quartz JDBCJobStore with RoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

For my application, we are using the spring's 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource

The target dataSources are configured and chosen based on request's domain URL.

```
    Eg: 

    qa.example.com ==> target datasource = DB1
    qa-test.example.com ==> target datasource = DB2
```

Following is the configuration for the same

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException, ConfigurationException {
        EERoutingDatabase routingDB = new EERoutingDatabase();

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = datasourceList();
        routingDB.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        return routingDB;
    }

public class EERoutingDatabase extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        // This is derived from the request's URL/Domain
        return SessionUtil.getDataSourceHolder();
    }
}
```

The task is now using Quartz JDBCJobStore to store the quartz jobs/triggers.

The preferred option is using JobStoreCMT.

We used the following config

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzConfig.class);
    private static final String QUARTZ_CONFIG_FILE = "ee-quartz.properties";


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * Spring wrapper over Quartz Scheduler bean
     */
    @Bean(name="quartzRealTimeScheduler")
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        LOG.info("Creating QUARTZ Scheduler for real time Job invocation");
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource(QUARTZ_CONFIG_FILE));
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        factory.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        jobFactory.setIgnoredUnknownProperties("applicationContext");
        return jobFactory;
    }
}
```

and following is the config in quartz properties file (ee-quartz.properties)

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

On starting the application, following exception occurs

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineTargetDataSource(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:202) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.expertly.config.EERoutingDatabase.determineTargetDataSource(EERoutingDatabase.java:60) ~[EERoutingDatabase.class:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:289) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore.initialize(LocalDataSourceJobStore.java:149) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1321) ~[quartz-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1525) ~[quartz-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.createScheduler(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:599) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:482) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-
```

beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]

It seems that

1. Quartz is trying to create connections with my datasource upfront.
   Since my dataSource isn't concrete one (its routing dataSource) and in addition doesn't have knowledge to which target Db to connect (at config time), it fails
2. Do we have any provision, where quartz can be used with RoutingDataSource? If Not, what would be the next best thing?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you can try making `SchedulerFactoryBean` as  @Lazy.

But It seems lazy initialization will not work [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8285), there is also a work around listed in the comments.

> Create `schedulerFactory` bean dynamically after
>   `ContextRefreshedEvent` received on root context.

Let us know, If this works.

Comment: I get this error and I dont even have a SchedulerFactoryBean  bean.